# Generic type constraint in variable/field declaration

Tags: typescript, generics

Suppose we have a generic interface:

```
export interface IKeyValue<K, V> {
    key: K;
    value: V;
}
```

Now, we want to declare a variable/field and limit which types could be used as `K` and `V`:

```
public items: IKeyValue<K extends Type1, V extends Type2>[];
```

The code above doesn't compile.

I'm using TypeScript 2.6.

How can we achieve it in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are not providing a definition but an instance.

```
public items: IKeyValue<Type1, Type2>[];
```

...is the valid syntax.

---

If you want to restrict the definition (interface) then you can provide the extends:

```
export interface IKeyValue<K extends Type1, V extends Type2> {
    key: K;
    value: V;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm from C# background and evidently searched for `where` constraint analog in TS, though it's not even needed :)